# Can't get webelement to print in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, unicode, selenium-webdriver

So this is the code that I am running:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
current_price = []
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://marketsworld.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("user_login_email")
email_field.send_keys("myusername")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("user_login_password")
password_field.send_keys("mypass")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("market_value")
instance = element.text
print instance
```

When I try to print `instance`, the output I get is

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/phuhzy/PycharmProjects/pychar_test/test2.py

(I don't get any output here. Only a blank line.)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Not sure why I am getting a blank line as the output. If I print it out as, `print type(instance)` , I get unicode back as the type.

Comment: Try printing `repr(instance)`, which more resembles the output in the interactive Python prompt. BTW: Upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was being an idiot and calling only on the first instance of market_value from the webpage which had more than one class name of market_value on the webpage. I"m also still quite new to python and will upgrade to 3 once i have the basics down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the element.text is empty or `None` and there is nothing to print.

Without knowing the actual data it is impossible to say.

You can test it by

```
if not instance:
    print "No data"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I later found that if i put it in a list and then printed the list I would get u' '. Which meant the unicode was an empty string. Also then realized I was an idiot and was calling only on the first instance of market_value from the webpage which had more than one class name of market_value on the webpage. I fixed this by calling element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("market_value") | then printed the len of element and found that there were 4 instances of market_value. 3 which had an empty string/no value and one which had the value I was looking for.